# Shutdown a computer from AIR/Flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, shutdown

I need to figure out how to shut down the computer from an Adobe AIR application. I have been trying to figure out how to do this, and without success.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this?  This is the kind of thing that AIR just isn't made for.

Comment: I wanted to build a auto-shutdown script mainly for myself, to shutdown after i finish recording tv with tv tuner card (while i am sleep). Besides AIR, all the other languages i know are web-based (and i am bad at java) - so air seemed like the best bet.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I don't think you can do this.

Comment: It's guaranteed to be impossible to do in a cross-platform manner.  Any OS where the user isn't running with administrator privileges (like linux) won't allow it.  I'd imagine Adobe would make it impossible for that reason alone.

Answer (score 3):

With Air 2.0 (currently available as beta) you can use the support for native code integration and call an external shutdown script.

Comment: can you please elaborate?!